# When $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is a Riemann surface?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions, complex-manifolds

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice, that is $\Lambda＝\{a\omega_1＋b\omega_2\mid a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$.

I heard that the necessarily and sufficient condition that  $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ be a Riemann surface is $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb R$.(Here, we give equivalent relation
to $\mathbb{C}$ by $x\sim y$ with $x-y\in\Lambda$).

But how can I formally prove this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Being a Riemann surface just means it is of complex dimension 1 and admits holomorphic transition maps between an atlas of charts. In your case an atlas can be chosen to have only 5 charts.

Comment: You should also say linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$. Over $\mathbb{C}$ they are dependent because it is only 1 dimensional as a complex vector space.

Comment: In the title and body, do you mean _compact_ Riemann surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Riemann surface iff

- $\omega_1,\omega_2$ are $\Bbb{R}$-linearly independent, in which case $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ is a compact Riemann surface (a complex torus, isomorphic to a projective elliptic curve),
- or $\Bbb{Q}$-linearly dependent, in which case it is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C/Z}$ or $\Bbb{C}$ depending on $\omega_j\ne 0$.

The word lattice assumes that $\omega_1,\omega_2$ are $\Bbb{R}$-linearly independent.

The non-obvious theorem is that they are often non-isomorphic as Riemann surfaces when changing the $\omega_1,\omega_2$ pair (this is proven usually with the unique space of holomorphic differential $\{c dz,c\in \Bbb{C}\}$)

Comment: What $\mathbb C$ /$ \mathbb Z$ looks like ? Why it is not Rieman surface?

Comment: To be clear you don't understand what Riemann surface and $\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$ means?

Comment: $\mathbb C / \mathbb Z$ is indeed a Riemann surface, but it is a noncompact one, and furthermore $\mathbb Z$ is not a lattice. So $\Lambda=\mathbb Z$ does not occur in the context of your question. If you drop the assumption that $\Lambda$ is a lattice then you admit such examples as $\omega_1 = 2$ and $\omega_2 = 3$; these are linearly *dependent* over $\mathbb R$, and $\Lambda = \mathbb Z$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I would add here that the word "lattice" was misused in the posed question: Either independence over the real numbers was forgotten or OP should not have used the word "lattice" in this setting.

Comment: @Lee Mosher  Could you tell me the proof of the fact that  C/Z is not compact ?

Comment: @Nekojiru The sequence $in$ doesn't have any convergent subsequence. A good exercice: let $f(z+\Bbb{Z}) = \exp(2i\pi z)$, it is a Riemann surface isomorphism $\Bbb{C/Z}\to X$, what is $X$?